# micronaut - how accept any request content and body

Tags: micronaut

I am trying to write a micronaut endpoint that consumes any type of content and get the raw body from the request and am facing a couple of challenges:

1. How to write the endpoint such as the request will be routed to it regardless of content-type? (micronaut defaults consumes to application/json)
2. How to read the body of such request?

I have tried the following:

```
@Controller(value = "/test", consumes = "*/*") 
public class MyController {

   @Post("/one")
   public String one(HttpRequest<?> req) {
      // req.getHeaders() returns expected headers
      // req.getParameters() seems to be fine
      // req.getBody(...) always return null regardless of which getBody method I use. I used the debugger to study what `req` contains and saw the underlying netty content appears empty
   }

   @Post("/two")
   public String two(HttpHeaders headers, HttpParameters params, @Body Object value) {
      // headers & params are good
      // body gives me a CompositeByteBuf... I find it surprising micronaut "leaks" the underlying netty bytebuf to the higher level impl 
   }

}
```

Couple of things to note:

- I can only hit these endpoints if I pass `-H "Content-Type: */*"` in my curl. I'd like these endpoints to be reachable regardless of the value of `Content-Type`.
- The first handler shows no body while the second shows there is one for the same request (just pointed at the other path). I would also prefer implementing my handler like handler #1.

Answer (score 1):

The wildcard was the problem, I was able to get handler #1 working with `HttpRequest<String>`:

```
@Post("/one")
public String one(HttpRequest<String> req) { ...
```

but the handler still does not accept requests with any content-type in spite of `consumes="*/*"`. I submitted an issue to the project: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/2334